# symfony2 Entity doesnot exist exception

Tags: php, symfony

Having trouble figuring out why I am getting this error.  The class `Judge_dates` exists in `AdminBundle\Entity` folder. I am not able to generate the table. getting the following error:

```
[Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\MappingException]                
  Class 'AdminBundle\Entity\Judge_dates' does not exist
```

`Judge_dates` has foreign key relationship with Judges table `judge_id column`.

Comment: You're going to need to give a small but complete sample of code/script that demonstrates your problem, in a way that other people can recreate your symptom.   In the process of producing that sample, you might have an "Aha!" moment, and solve your own problem.   If not, other people will have a chance of helping.   As is, nobody can even guess what is causing your problem.

Comment: solved this issue.  Removed the Judge_dates entity class and added it again. worked!!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have disabled doctrine automapping option and need enable it

```
doctrine:
    orm:
        auto_mapping: true
```

or need add bundle AdminBundle to mapping

```
doctrine:   
    orm:
       entity_managers:
            default:
                connection: default
                mappings:
                    AdminBundle: ~
```

Comment: these mappings already exist.  I already have other entity classes which are working fine. Just this one is giving me problem

Comment: btw.. which file  should the second mapping go in.

Comment: Can you show code of AdminBundle\Entity\Judge_dates , btw better use camel case format for name i.e JudgeDates and I belive it can be the reason of missed mapping

Comment: I removed the JudgeDates entity and added it again. It generated the table.  Now I want to add the foreign key relationship to JudgeDates table to refer to Judge table.  can you help me with the mapping.

Comment: It is little bit hard to understand what you mean "add the foreign key relationship". Do you need Judge and JudgeDates be connected "OneToMany"? http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html

Comment: thx for the link.    onetoOne:
      Judge:
        targetEntity: Admin\Judge
        joinColumn:
          name:  judgeId
          referencedColumnName: id

Comment: I think I will mark this problem as solved and open a new question for the foreign key issue.

Answer (score 0):

solved this issue. Removed the Judge_dates entity class and added it again. worked!!